# mod_rewrite rules conflicting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm using mod_rewrite and there's some jquery/AJAX that loads in the content always using the new url: **/user/register/**

```
RewriteRule ^user/register/?$ register.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

but i also want to deny [or redirect] letting someone goto the **register.php** file directly.
i tried to add this below, but it broke the top rule from working.

```
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ - [F,L]
```

how do i do both in the rules?

Comment: Is it essential that both are called register.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ - [F,L]
```

This isn't going to work by itself, because your other rule rewrites the URI to `register.php`, then when the rewrite engine loops, this rule gets applied and ultimately a 403 is returned. You need to check against the actual request itself:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /register\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```